# Best practices for hosting marketing/landing pages

Tags: php, hosting, rackspace-cloud

I am working on a web application (LAMP stack) that has the code/dependencies for the marketing/landing pages tied in with the application code.  The app is hosted on the rackspace cloud.

I've been thinking about whether or not these two sites should be left together, separated on the same server, or hosted on entirely separate servers.

What is common when it comes to hosting marketing/landing pages for web apps?  If I need to host the sites on separate ip's or separate servers, what steps will I need to take to have two separate ip's referring to the same base URL. Is it going to be a problem to have a https connection from two seperate ips?  If it is, I can likely have all the secure pages on one IP.  What would be the correct term used to describe two ips pointing to one base url?

The structure would be:

example.com/landing-page (hosted on x.x.x.1)
example.com/module/app-page (hosted on x.x.x.2)

Any articles or blog posts that discuss this topic?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want the 2 web apps to have access to the same underlying PHP files, like functions, classes, etc? Yeah, that's possible, but not sure if the Rackspace cloud allows this. A dedicated server that you can set 2 IP addresses to with separate virtual hosts will allow this with simple symbolic links and as long as the files are executable by the web user (usually apache)

Hope that answers your question. If you give more details, I may be able to answer your question more accurately.

Comment: http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3103-no-framework-needed -- after reading this I think I will completely separate the code and serve static HTML only on the marketing page.  What would be helpful is whatever code needs to be added to the vhosts file to create the correct relationship.  What are your thoughts on running one/server vs both on the same server?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The main thing is that both apps have underlying access to the file system where the files are kept. That really has nothing to do with the upper layers such as vhost config, ip addresses, or 1 vs 2 servers. If you want 2 web apps to have access to the same code, you have 2 choices..... make sure both web apps can see the same files or copy them and maintain 2 separate copies of the same code. There are so many solutions to your problem, and it is a matter of preference... One would be to use subversion and just check out the files to each site. Another would be to use a san or symlinks